# Merge two dataframes where requirements are met

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes that I am trying to merge where certain criteria is met.

I want to merge DF2 into DF1 where the Client MAC and AP MAC match but also where the 'Description' contains 'AP' and the 'Client VLAN' is equal to '1234'. I then want to populate the 'AP Interface' with the corresponding 'Interface'.

My actual DF1 is over 10k rows and DF2 is typically 300 or less.

DF1:

| Switch | Interface | Description | Client VLAN | Client MAC |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| SW1 | Gi1/0/1 | AP Port | 1234 | 1234.1234.1234 |
| SW1 | Gi1/0/1 | AP Port | 2344 | 3210.3210.3210 |
| SW1 | Gi1/0/2 | AP Port | 1234 | 3456.3456.3456 |
| SW2 | Gi2/0/5 | Computer | 2343 | 6543.6543.6543 |
| SW2 | Gi2/0/8 | Trunk | 1234 | 2345.2345.2345 |
| SW3 | Te1/1/1 | AP Port | 1234 | 7890.7890.7890 |
| SW4 | Gi3/0/6 | AP Port | 1234 | 2345.2345.2345 |

DF2:

| AP Name | AP Intf | AP MAC |
| --- | --- | --- |
| AP1 |  | 1234.1234.1234 |
| AP2 |  | 3456.3456.3456 |
| AP3 |  | 2345.2345.2345 |
| AP4 |  | 7890.7890.7890 |

Desired output:

| Switch | Interface | Description | Client VLAN | Client MAC | AP Name | AP Intf | AP MAC |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| SW1 | Gi1/0/1 | AP Port | 1234 | 1234.1234.1234 | AP1 | Gi1/0/1 | 1234.1234.1234 |
| SW1 | Gi1/0/1 | AP Port | 2344 | 3210.3210.3210 |  |  |  |
| SW1 | Gi1/0/2 | AP Port | 1234 | 3456.3456.3456 | AP2 | Gi1/0/2 | 3456.3456.3456 |
| SW2 | Gi2/0/5 | Computer | 2343 | 6543.6543.6543 |  |  |  |
| SW2 | Gi2/0/8 | Trunk | 1234 | 2345.2345.2345 |  |  |  |
| SW3 | Te1/1/1 | AP Port | 1234 | 7890.7890.7890 | AP4 | Te1/1/1 | 7890.7890.7890 |
| SW4 | Gi3/0/6 | AP Port | 1234 | 2345.2345.2345 | AP3 | Gi3/0/6 | 2345.2345.2345 |

The code I'm using that is giving me the below output:

```
def helper(data, col): return data.groupby(col).cumcount()

df1['Client MAC'] = df1['Client MAC'].fillna("")
df2['AP MAC'] = df2['AP MAC'].fillna("")

df = df1.merge(df2, left_on=['Client MAC', helper(df1, ['Client MAC'])], right_on=['AP MAC', helper(df2, \
                        ['AP MAC'])], how='left').drop(columns='key_1')
```

Current output:

| Switch | Interface | Description | Client VLAN | Client MAC | AP Name | AP Intf | AP MAC |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| SW1 | Gi1/0/1 | AP Port | 1234 | 1234.1234.1234 | AP1 | Gi1/0/1 | 1234.1234.1234 |
| SW1 | Gi1/0/1 | AP Port | 2344 | 3210.3210.3210 |  |  |  |
| SW1 | Gi1/0/2 | AP Port | 1234 | 3456.3456.3456 | AP2 | Gi1/0/2 | 3456.3456.3456 |
| SW2 | Gi2/0/5 | Computer | 2343 | 6543.6543.6543 |  |  |  |
| SW2 | Gi2/0/8 | Trunk | 1234 | 2345.2345.2345 | AP3 | Gi3/0/6 | 2345.2345.2345 |
| SW3 | Te1/1/1 | AP Port | 1234 | 7890.7890.7890 | AP4 | Te1/1/1 | 7890.7890.7890 |
| SW4 | Gi3/0/6 | AP Port | 1234 | 2345.2345.2345 |  |  |  |

Answer (score 3):

With `merge` + [`mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html) operations:

```
df = df1.merge(df2, left_on='Client MAC', right_on='AP MAC', how='left')
df['AP Intf'] = (df['AP Intf'].mask(df['Description'].str.contains('AP')
                                    & df['Client VLAN'].eq(1234), df['Interface']))
```

---

```
  Switch Interface Description  Client VLAN      Client MAC AP Name   AP Intf          AP MAC
0   SW1   Gi1/0/1     AP Port          1234  1234.1234.1234     AP1   Gi1/0/1   1234.1234.1234
1   SW1   Gi1/0/1     AP Port          2344  3210.3210.3210     NaN       NaN              NaN
2   SW1   Gi1/0/2     AP Port          1234  3456.3456.3456     AP2   Gi1/0/2   3456.3456.3456
3   SW2   Gi2/0/5    Computer          2343  6543.6543.6543     NaN       NaN              NaN
4   SW2   Gi2/0/8       Trunk          1234  2345.2345.2345     AP3       NaN   2345.2345.2345
5   SW3   Te1/1/1     AP Port          1234  7890.7890.7890     AP4   Te1/1/1   7890.7890.7890
6   SW4   Gi3/0/6     AP Port          1234  2345.2345.2345     AP3   Gi3/0/6   2345.2345.2345
```